# Как получить посты в чате, канале Telegram

Tags: python, парсер, telegram-bot, telegram

Нужно парсить любой канал в Telegram. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: https://proglib.io/p/pishem-prostoy-grabber-dlya-telegram-chatov-na-python-2019-11-06
Здесь все расписано просто и понятно, если знания Python не хромают - все поймешь.

Answer (score 2):

Вам понадобится библиотека telethon. Вам нужно сделать while устоновить условие на boolean переменную и внутри while сделать try в котором пытаемся получить сообщение по id из заранее созданой переменной и добавляем к этой переменной 1. А в except изменяем переменную из условия на False.